# .htaccess RewriteCond tested after the rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've been trying to get something to work for the past two hours without any luck. I've looked for help on google and apache docs, but I still can't find a way out of this one. Here's the thing:

I have two files:

```
index.php
public/css/screen.css
```

I want that any URL typed in the browser redirects to index.php?url=$1 if it is not a file. If it is, it should redirect to public/$1. I tried using the following rewrite rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Unfortunately, since the rewrite only happens after RewriteCond is satisfied, the first two RewriteCond will test against css/screen.css instead of public/css/screen.css.

Is there a magic flag that tells apache do the RewriteRule, test if the RewriteConds are true and then undo the rewrite if not? How would you guys do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The RewriteRule is compared first, but no substitution occurs unless all the conditions also match -- you can't influence this directly.

Since REQUEST_FILENAME in .htaccess is what the server *already* mapped the URL to, you should be doing e.g.:

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 -f
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]

where $1 is the "leftover" part of what was originally requested

You will also need a proper RewriteBase, since you are rewriting to a relative URL.